# Change in variable values upon recursion, Python 3

Tags: python, variables, recursion

Hey so im pretty new to programming in general and I was having a crack at a question I found for the collatz function,

The code I wrote after some trial and error is as follows:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number//2
        print(number)
        return number
    elif number%2 != 0:
        number = 3*number + 1
        print(number)
        return number

n = int(input("plz enter the number:")) 

while n != 1:
    n = collatz(n)
```

Output:

```
plz enter the number:3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

This code works but im not sure how the variable values are being alloted, cuz after running this program I can see that in the shell "number = 3" but "n = 1", why is this the case? Shouldnt "number" also equal to 1? Because I am returning the value of number within the function?

Also just to clear my concepts, at the initial moment when I input n = 3, at that moment n = number = 3, then does this returned value of "number" automatically become the new value of n, when i call it in the while loop?
Just wanted to check cuz im a little weak when it comes to doing stuff that needs to pass parameters.

edit:

Why is this case diff then what was just answered?

```
def testfile(number):
    number = number -1 
    print(number)
    return number

n = int(input("enter:"))

while n != 2:
    n = testfile(n)
```

Output:

```
enter:5
4
3
2
```

When the input is given as n = 5, then why does number = 3 instead of 5 as was just explained below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how your program works.

You ask for a number and store it in variable `n`.

You open a loop which continues until `n` is `1`

Every time the loop repeats, you're calling your function and passing a COPY of n. If you add one to the copy inside the function, your original `n` will not change.

The COPY is called `number`. You perform your little tricks with `number`, output it to the screen, and here's the confusing part: you return a copy of **number** right back to your loop. And where does it go? It goes right back to `n`. This overwrites whatever was in `n` previously.

Comment: Thanks! 1 more follow up plz,                                                                                                           `def testfile(number):`
    `number = number -1` 
    `print(number)`
   `return number`
    
`n = int(input("enter:"))`

`while n != 2:`
    `n = testfile(n)` according to what you have said over here then when I input n = 5 over here, after running this program, the value of number should be 5, but thats not the case, the value of number is 3, why is this case different then whats happening above?

Comment: @nz2020 the code is somewhat difficult to read but if you input 5, your output will be 4, 3, 2

Comment: I just added an edit, i was talking about after the output, when I check the value of number within the shell

Comment: @nz2020 clearly, number is actually 4, not 3. It's 4 because you subtract one from it BEFORE you display it on screen (with `print`)

Comment: ehh, I can assure you that when i'm running the given code, then the value of the variable "number" is showing up as 3 in the shell.

Comment: @nz2020 I hope I don't come across as rude but I am decently certain that the shell is only confusing you, not helping you. Just pay attention to your outputs, they are telling you the truth here.